# Printf: differences in Java's and C's implementation

Tags: java, c, printf

I noticed today that I can't use `*` to pass width or precision arguments to Java's implementation of `printf`.

That is, the following arguments to `printf` are valid in C, but not Java:

```
"%*d", 10, 3
"%-*d", 10, 3
"%0*d", 10, 3
"%*.5f", 11, 1.0/9
"%-11.*f", 5, 1.0/9
"%0*.*f", 11, 5, 1.0/9
```

Are there any other implementation differences I should be aware of?

Comment: For Java, see the API documentation of [`java.util.Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: `printf("[% + + 0 + ----- +    +6d]\n", 42);` is valid C to print 42 left justified in a field of width 6 with a + sign enclosed in `[]` and terminated by a linefeed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't think of it as differences. I'd just read through the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) carefully and go entirely from that. Thinking in terms of differences is likely to lead to things slipping through the net.

In other words, I'd treat the *similarities* as coincidences, and assume the two are different until proven otherwise :)

Comment: fair enough.  I tend to think of `printf` and its format as a standard, but I can try to shift my thinking to accept reality.

Answer (score 1):

One difference hit me just recently: when printing a floating point number with %g (automatically choose %e or %f) the precision flag is different:

```
Java: precision = 
  "number of fractional digits after the decimal point" (%f, %e)
  "total number of digits in the resulting magnitude after rounding"  (%g  %G) 

C: precision = 
  "number of fractional digits after the decimal point" (%f %e )   
  "maximum number of significant digits" (%g  %G)
```